# Get the value in square brackets array php

Tags: php, arrays

I would get the data in square brackets array php.

I have this array :

```
Array
(
    'ETHBTC' => 0.02813100,
    'LTCBTC' => 0.00794700,
    'BNBBTC' => 0.00126500,
    'BTCUSDT' => 3994.17000000,
    'ETHUSDT' => 112.32000000

);
```

For example I would get ethbtc, ltcbtc for values.

How can I do this?

I need your help.

Comment: Have you found a suitable solution in any of those # answers? If not, tell us more. Otherwise do and accept the solution that is best for you to close the question - see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to get the keys in that array use `array_keys($a)` // $a is your array

Comment: Thank you very much. I will chose your answer

Answer (score 0):

To obtain list of key values from an array use PHP function [array_keys()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) that returns all the keys or a subset of the keys of an array.